# How can I make a while True break if certain key is pressed? [Python]

Tags: python, windows

My script make a while True: begin with the F4 pressed, but I want it to stop when the F2 is pressed, how can I do it?

I'm trying this (using pyhook) but doesn't work...

```
def onKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.KeyID == 115:      #F4
        while True:
            selectAndCopy(468,722)
            getClipboard()
            time.sleep(2)
            if event.KeyID == 113:
                break
    return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not changing `event` within your loop, so you wouldn't expect `event.KeyID` to suddenly become 113 when it was 115 previously.

What you might do is, on handling an F4 keypress, start a timer that does the selectAndCopy every two seconds. When you get another event with an F2 keystroke, kill the timer.

It could look something like this:

```
def onKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.KeyID == 115:      #F4
        startTimer(doTimer, 2)
    if event.KeyID == 113:
        stopTimer()

def doTimer():
    selectAndCopy(468,722)
    getClipboard()
```

You would have to provide or find implementations of `startTimer()` and `stopTimer()`.

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: I don't know anything about pyhook, so I'll make some stuff up and see what I can do.

Comment: with threading.Timer I can make a timer, but it doesn't loop =/

Answer (score 0):

Make key event which

1. change variable **True with F4** and if the variable is still True do new timer event
   for example in [Tkinter](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html)

   mylabel.after(2000, process)  # process is the function to do your stuff
2. change variable **False with F2** and
   cancels the timer (after_cancel)