# How can I exit a while with a key ? [Python]

Tags: python, windows, while-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a while True break if certain key is pressed? [Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589172/how-can-i-make-a-while-true-break-if-certain-key-is-pressed-python)

I have this code:

```
def enterCategory():
    time.sleep(0.2)
    if entercount == 1:
        mouseMove(*position[5])
        while win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[1] != 65567:
            mouseMove(*position[5])
            mouseMove(*position[4])
        mouseLeftClick()

def onKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.KeyID == 13:  #ENTER
        print '\n'
        mouseLeftClick()
        enterCountInc()
        enterCategory()
        print '\n'
    if event.KeyID == 113: #F2
        doLogin()
        enterCountReset()
    return True

hook.KeyDown = onKeyboardEvent
hook.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

and it work like this:

When I press F2, the script will fill some forms and wait for my enter to login, then, when I press enter, the script jump to a part of the screen and check if that part is a link (enterCategory() part), and if it's a link, the script do successfully what I want, but if something goes wrong with the login, the position[4] and [5] will never be a link, and the script will be at infinity loop...

How can I solve that? How can I do something so when I press F2, it exist the while and try the login again?

Sorry if I'm not understandable =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the handling of F2 to set a global flag (e.g., one named `proceed`) to `False`, and where you now have `while win32gui...`, have, instead

```
global proceed
proceed = True
while proceed and win32gui...
```

Not elegant, but then neither is the cursor-shape analysis to find out if the mouse is on a link;-).